# Using Top and Skip in Microsoft Graph to implement paging

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying (using the .NET SDK) to get paged DriveItems (a folder's content).

I don't understand what **$skip** [is supposed to do](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters#skip), or it doesn't seem to work.

Even testing it from the [Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer#). $skip is ignored. With or without including also a $top parameter ($top does work fine).

Example:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/myFolde/subFolder:/children?$skip=4`

or

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/myFolde/subFolder:/children?$skip=4&top=4`

or

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/myFolde/subFolder:/children?$skip=2&top=4`

It always start from the first item (as if $skip wasn't specified).

I'm doing this, because there seems to be [a problem with NextPageRequest](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/54).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the NextPageRequest has been resolved. Skip is not supported by the OneDrive endpoint.

Comment: About Skip is not being supported, too bad it wasn't documented. The only way to know if a particular query parameter works or not is trial and error?